# setTimeout not working with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I have a jquery extended function that works perfectly but when i pass it through the setTimout it does not wait the the specified period and runs straight away.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
  setTimeout($.mainmenuslider({
    trigger:'close'
  }),6000);  
});
```

Any Ideas???

Answer (score 15):

You need to pass an anonymous method to do what you want, like this:

```
jQuery(function($) {    
    setTimeout(function() {
      $.mainmenuslider({
        trigger:'close'
      });
    }, 6000);    
});
```

Otherwise you're trying to pass the *result* of the function (making it execute immediately, and run nothing later).

Comment: saved my butt just now! thanks :) was chasing down a race condition and couldn't figure out why I couldn't get rid of it

Answer (score 8):

You're *calling* the function right there when you're trying to *set up* the timeout to happen later.  Instead:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $.mainmenuslider({trigger:'close'});
  }, 6000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This!!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
  setTimeout("$.mainmenuslider({
    trigger:'close'
  })",6000);  
});
```

while using the setTimeout() , always try specifying the action need to be called in quotes.

Ex:

```
setTimeout("call_this_function()", 4000);
```

Comment: That is not actually a good idea. Look at the other answers for examples of the proper way to do this.

Comment: 4 spaces before a line format it as code. Select a block and hit `ctr-k` to do this.