# Function isn't delayed for some reason

Tags: javascript, jquery

These is main function

```
function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
    {

        var docViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();


        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

        if (elemBottom >=docViewTop) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        };
    }
```

This is delayed

```
var timeoutSrc
    function delayedSrc(elem){
        timeoutSrc=window.setTimeout(isScrolledIntoView(elem), 2200)}
```

Here I call it:

```
delayedSrc($("#result"));
```

But by alert test message I can tell, that there is no delay.

Comment: You are *calling* the function right away (and passing the *result* to setTimeout)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8462381/settimeout-callback-executed-immediately

Comment: possible duplicate of [setTimeout not working with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264963/settimeout-not-working-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the function, then passing it to `setTimeout`. One way to fix this:

```
var timeoutSrc;

function delayedSrc(elem){
    timeoutSrc= window.setTimeout(function () {
        isScrolledIntoView(elem);
    }, 2200);
}
```

Comment: Although I had you by exactly 1 second, I will concede that your answer is superior with your judicious use of semicolons. Well played, sir. :)

Comment: I'm laughing, but I'm also shaking my head that this question doesn't have most close votes.

Comment: It's always difficult to find the *exact* dupe for these, since they're all pretty localized. [This one is close](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264963/settimeout-not-working-with-jquery), but not quite.

Comment: @RobHruska I think [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410590/spam-spam-spam-spam#comment23528297_16410590) counted as a close with prejudice. `:)`

Comment: Lol, yeah, we owned that one.